# Webpack imported module remains undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Update 2 - Fixed:**

I had somehow created a circular dependency while refactoring. Breaking out some logic to a separate module fixed the issue.

**Conclusion**: Circular dependencies in Webpack can lead to exported modules becoming undefined.

---

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to import modules from an index file a couple of folders down. For some reason the import fails.

This is a large project and imports are working just fine throughout.

Am I missing something?

- I've tried using an alias => exact alias works in one part of the project but fails in this file.
- I've attempted clearing git cache to no avail.
- I've restarted (to clear any caching). Nothing.
- I've removed node modules and reinstalled everything.
- Cleared NPM cache
- Cleared Babel cache
- Renamed folders and files to force webpack to look elsewhere
- Is there nay kind of webpack caching going on?

The problem appears to be growing. In modules where the offending item successfully imported earlier it now fails.

At this point I fear it's glaringly obvious and I'm just daft. I'm ready to quit.

**UPDATE:**

Still fighting this issue. The problem now persists across my project, specifically related to my `data` folder.

**Import code (src/actions/apiActions.js)**

```
import * as config from './../data/index.js'

console.log(config)
```

**Export code (src/data/index.js)**

```
// updated appConfiguration from default to regular export

import {
  appConfiguration as appConf,
  getGoogleKey,
  getPort,
  withSamples
} from './app.config.js'

import { formatSubmittedData } from './formatSubmittedData'

export { appConf, getGoogleKey, getPort, withSamples, formatSubmittedData }
```

**File structure**

```
+ src
  + actions
    + apiActions.js
  + data
    + app.config.js
    + formatSubmittedData.js
    + index.js
```

**Console Output**

[image: nothing in module]

---

**Sample Code:**

```
import * as things from './../../index.js'

console.log('main item', things)
console.log('selected item', things.appConf)
```

[image: Console output of issue]

**File I'm exporting from:**

```
import appConfiguration from './app.config'
import { getGoogleKey, withSamples } from './app.config'
import { formatSubmittedData } from './formatSubmittedData'

export {
  appConfiguration as appConf,
  formatSubmittedData,
  getGoogleKey,
  withSamples
}
```

**export in app.config.js**

[image]

Comment: How are your functions exported from './app.config' ?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. Two things: 1. it shows in the console.log for `things` so it's clearly exporting - even though it fails when logging `things.appConf`. 2. I'm successfully importing `appConf` and `getGoogleKey` in other parts of the app from the index export.

Comment: If it is a cache issue does restarted (to clear any caching) mean clearing your browsers cache ?

Comment: I've cleared both git cache, and browser cache. I've also restarted my machine hoping it was some kind of webpack caching in memory.